# What is the encoding of this data?

Tags: encryption, encoding

Who can tell me the encoding type of these data? It doesn't seem to be base64.

```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```

(Line endings inserted for readability)

Comment: Where did you find this encoded data? In an e-mail? In a YouTube HTTP 500 error? And: is it the whole data or only part of it?

Comment: The only reason why it *couldn't* be a base64-encoding (or variant) is if more than 64 symbols (excluding any padding/formatting symbols) are used. Just like Arabic numerals are different than Brahmi numerals - and yet both encode base10 numbers. Anyway, this is not a good place for games to "reverse engineer" encrypted/encoded data.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be base64. If you add a single equal ('=') for padding to the end your decoder should be happy (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

Decoded it's 1568 bytes which mod 16 is zero. This histogram of byte value occurance is flat. So I'd guess something encrypted with a 128 bit block cipher like AES.

Comment: +1 for the histogram insight. And since "who knows" with any decent encryption we (or at least, I) can comfortably move on ..

Comment: I doubt it's AES though, as we can readily see some non random structures, like the strings of `FZu+`, `0`s and the last line.

Comment: **The raw data is a small jpeg image.** Well, I also try some encryption algorithms (such as aes, des etc.), and then encode the ciphertext with base-64, the output differs very much from the data posted above.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* look like base64 to me. Most variants of base64 include the following characters:

```
A-Z  a-z  0-9  +  /  (and = for padding)
```

However, if it were proper base64 it would end with a single `=` as padding, as the 2091 characters don't exactly fit a number of bytes.

Your data doesn't seem to decode to anything readable, so it might be binary data, or encrypted (or both). Only with thorough knowledge of cryptography systems, and a lot of hints and luck, might some expert be able to figure out the encryption used (if any), but that's beyond the scope of this site.

Without more information as to the source of the data, we can only guess.